# Product collection filter by Product attribute set id in admin grid(programmatically)

Tags: magento2, product

I want to override product collection in Magento product grid in admin side.

[image]

Please let me know which file I need to override for collection filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Plugin and add below code in your admin's **di.xml** file

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
    <plugin name="product-collection-sorting" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\ProductDataProvider" sortOrder="999"/>
</type>
```

**Now create file [Vendor][Module]\Plugin\ProductDataProvider**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider as RelatedProductDataProvider;


class ProductDataProvider extends RelatedProductDataProvider
{

public function afterGetData(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject,
        $result
    )
    {
       
        $subject->getCollection()->clear();
        $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => 4])->load();
        $items = $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => 4])->toArray();
        $totalRecords = $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => 4])->load()->getSize();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently i did similar by using prefernce
`<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" type="vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" />`

Comment: It's showing me this error after overriding the file

Notice: Undefined index: websites in /var/www/html/sterling/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Websites.php on line 84
Exception in /var/www/html/sterling/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

Comment: I have added category filter to product grid by overriding same file. plz check [link](https://www.rltsquare.com/blog/magento-2-add-categories-column-to-product-grid-in-admin-and-make-it-filterable/)